# SwiftUI .rotation3dEffect animation doesn't have desired depth effect in Apple Watch List Row

Tags: swift, swiftui, apple-watch, swiftui-list, swiftui-animation

When .rotation3dEffect is animated in an Apple Watch listRow, the row appears to animate above the prior row (which is desired), but the animation appears to take place under the next row which ruins the 3d effect. How can this animation also take place above the next row?

[image: Undesired 3d rotation animation]

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestView: View {
let colors: [Color] = [.red,.blue,.green,.pink,.purple,.black,.brown,.cyan,.indigo,.teal]

var body: some View {
    List {
        ForEach(0..<10) { i in
            RowView(color: colors[i])
        }
    }
    .listStyle(.carousel)
}
}

struct RowView: View {
let color: Color

@State private var rotationAngle: Double = 0

var body: some View {
    Button(action: {
        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 3.0)) {
            rotationAngle += 180
        }
    }) {
        HStack {
            Text("Test Row")
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(height: 100)
        .background(color)
        .rotation3DEffect(
            Angle.degrees(rotationAngle),
            axis: (0,1,0),
            perspective: 1.0
    )
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is your `perspective` setting. In order to simulate perspective, Apple makes it seem like one view is behind another. This gives the illusion of distance. The farther away from 0, the more a view will appear behind another. If you set `perspective` to 0, you are saying I am looking top down on this view, so it won't be behind another view. If you want some perspective, you need some gap between your different views, so no overlap occurs when you trigger the animation.

```
struct RowView: View {
    let color: Color
    
    @State private var rotationAngle: Double = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 3.0)) {
                rotationAngle += 180
            }
        }) {
            HStack {
                Text("Test Row")
                Spacer()
            }
            .frame(height: 100)
            .background(color)
            .rotation3DEffect(
                Angle.degrees(rotationAngle),
                axis: (0,1,0),
                // Set the perspective to 0 and it animates
                // without being under another view.
                perspective: 0)
        }
    }
}
```